# Partial Derivatives with respect to independent variables

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, chain-rule

Could I please get help with the following question?

Let $ =  + $ and $ =  − $
Express $\frac{^2}{^2}$
and $\frac{^2}{^2}$
in terms of partial derivatives of $$ with respect to the independent variables $$ and $$.

Comment: Simply use the chain rule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the chain rule we have

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial \xi}\frac{\partial \xi}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial \eta}\frac{\partial \eta}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial \xi}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial \eta}$$
$$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial \xi}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial \eta}\right)=\frac{\partial}{\partial \xi}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial \xi}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial \eta}\right)+\frac{\partial}{\partial \eta}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial \xi}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial \eta}\right)$$
$$=\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial\xi^2}+\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial\xi\partial\eta}+\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial\eta\partial\xi}+\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial\eta^2}$$

etc.

Comment: In this case, what do ξ=x+y and η=x−y relations help with to reach the final answer? I can see the main function differential is related to ξ and η.

Comment: What are $\frac{\partial \xi}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial \eta}{\partial x}$? The final answer is shown above, $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}$ is expressed in terms of the partial derivatives of $f$ with respect to the independent variables $\xi$ and $\eta$.

Comment: Ah, I understand you have used the fact that ∂ξ/∂x=1 and ∂η/∂x=1 as well by the given relation. Thank you.

Comment: Correct, now do the same with $y$.

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact that $\displaystyle\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial \zeta}\frac{\partial \zeta}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial \eta}\frac{\partial \eta}{\partial x}$